# Why can't I install Oracle Java 6?

Tags: java, oracle

I'm trying to install a Java 6 JRE on Ubuntu 16.04.

As I have done many times before, I did:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java6-installer
```

... which gave me this error:

```
 Downloading Oracle Java 6...
--2016-11-10 08:51:35--  http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/6u45-b06/jdk-6u45-linux-x64.bin
Resolving download.oracle.com (download.oracle.com)... 146.57.254.26, 146.57.254.43
Connecting to download.oracle.com (download.oracle.com)|146.57.254.26|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Moved Temporarily
Location: https://edelivery.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/6u45-b06/jdk-6u45-linux-x64.bin [following]
--2016-11-10 08:51:35--  https://edelivery.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/6u45-b06/jdk-6u45-linux-x64.bin
Resolving edelivery.oracle.com (edelivery.oracle.com)... 23.209.61.60, 2600:1418:3:1a2::2d3e, 2600:1418:3:18b::2d3e
Connecting to edelivery.oracle.com (edelivery.oracle.com)|23.209.61.60|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Moved Temporarily
Location: https://www.oracle.com/splash/edelivery/index.html [following]
--2016-11-10 08:51:35--  https://www.oracle.com/splash/edelivery/index.html
Resolving www.oracle.com (www.oracle.com)... 23.209.61.60, 2600:1418:3:1a2::2d3e, 2600:1418:3:18b::2d3e
Connecting to www.oracle.com (www.oracle.com)|23.209.61.60|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 503 Service Unavailable
2016-11-10 08:51:35 ERROR 503: Service Unavailable.

download failed
```

Does anyone know if Oracle's Java 6 is gone forever?

I guess for now I'm going to go to the [openjdk source](https://java.net/projects/openjdk6/downloads/) but maybe someone knows of a workaround for the Oracle Java?

Comment: `edelivery.oracle.com` is out of commission. You'll need to follow [the manual method](http://askubuntu.com/questions/56104/how-can-i-install-sun-oracles-proprietary-java-jdk-6-7-8-or-jre), getting the link from [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/java-archive-downloads-javase6-419409.html#jdk-6u45-oth-JPR).

Comment: :( argh. I did actually try that and am getting this [delivery failure](https://www.oracle.com/splash/edelivery/index.html) message.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's gone forever unless you have a support contract with Oracle.

Java 6 is no longer provided to the general public by Oracle because [it reached end-of-life way back in February 2013](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/eol-135779.html), so you can't download it from Oracle unless you have a support contract with Oracle, which allows you to [manually download it (after logging in)](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/java-archive-downloads-javase6-419409.html) until December 2018.

I'd recommend using Java 8 or later. It still gets security updates, and it will compile and run Java 6 programs just fine. If you need to compile something so that it will run on a Java 6 JVM, [you just need to add `-target 1.6` to your `javac` line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11364761).

Answer (score 0):

You can download the SE 6 here:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/java-archive-downloads-javase6-419409.html

Answer (score -1):

You can't download any java archive, not only 6. This issue occurs all around the world (starts today). It seems like the Oracle site problem. 
UK, USA, Europe, Russia - users from different countries confirm the problem.

You can install Open JDK instead.

[Similar issue from USA](https://superuser.com/questions/1144370/cant-download-64bit-java-from-oracle-download-list-country-listed-as-blocked).

[And one more from Italy](https://community.oracle.com/thread/3989958).